# Y capacitors regulations at the secondary of a class-I power supply

Tags: power-supply, regulations

I know safety-rated Y1/Y2 capacitors are required at the AC line input for EMI purposes, but what about the isolated secondary of a class I power supply?
What are the safety regulations here?

Can I connect between "+" and chassis ground and "-" and chassis ground non-safety rated Y capacitors for EMI suppression?

Comment: The capacitors aren't *required* for EMI; it's theoretically possible, just impractical, to get adequate EMI filtering without them. What *is* required is that, if capacitors are used, they must be Y-rated.

Answer (score 0):

Insulation required between secondary side (presumably, of SELV type?) and ground does not depend on the power supply type, but on product requirements.  Whether a power supply is compatible with that system, depends.

For example, a class I power supply could presumably fail in such a way that the secondary side becomes shorted to chassis GND, which is presumably a safe condition for the user, but is no longer isolated.  It's up to the equipment designer whether that's unsafe for the user in turn, or what.

In other words, the power supply selection is driven by product requirements, not the other way around. Conversely, if power supply choice were fixed, then its rating sets the maximum isolation, and insulation type, you can specify in turn.

For medical devices, 1 or 2 MOPP (Means Of Patient Protection) may be required, of some specified breakdown voltage.  Safety type capacitors may be desired in this case.

Standards include IEC/UL 60950-1 (still somewhat in use, mostly superseded), 62368-1, 60601-1 for medical, etc.  Many are harmonized (between IEC, UL, ANSI, etc.), so are available through either organization(s).